# Missing Gravatar

Tags: bug, gravatar

My gravatar on posts seems to have disappeared:

[alt text http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6943/nogravatar.png](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6943/nogravatar.png)

But it's still shows in my User Profile:

[alt text http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7752/yesgravatar.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7752/yesgravatar.png)

**EDIT:**  Well, now  it's back, guess it was just a Gravatar bug.  Please help me close this question now that it's no longer relevant.

Comment: I still see it in both places. Of course, I get heavily cached here, so it might not be your current Gravatar anyway.

Comment: I've seen it happening on and off; the user and timing seem to be random, although one thing that appears to be consistent is that it only happens for the auto-generated gravatars, not the custom ones.

Comment: @Aarobot I saw it happen to Robert Harvey's avatar about a week ago, actually, so I think it is not just auto-gens. @Lance Today mine is currently the opposite: I see it on my posts but not in my profile.

Comment: This is another instance where it was closed unnecessarily.  It still happens sometimes, like today.  The closing and stuff is really used too much as a way to 'get' users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this link](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/576cdd58ab7df19c6715121c7806bbf6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) directly.

It yields a 504 Gateway time-out (so I suspect this is a temporary problem @gravatar - it doesn't look like SO is misbehaving).

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/2565/screenshot20100518at221.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/2565/screenshot20100518at221.png)